# Create a button that generate specify column to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have just post a question last week. The question is about finding a the missing cell in a list. It is the post link [Button click find empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419737/excel-vba-button-click-find-empty-cell)
Base on the previous question i would like to add on some new function. 
[image: It is the table normally look like] Red column is mandatory field and green is optional field.
I would like to add a new column and create a button that could generate all the mandatory fields to a new worksheet.
[image: This is the new table look like]

As you can see, there are a new column and a new button that was created.
Now, I would like to use the "generate button" to generate all the mandatory(Red) fields into a new worksheet call "important". However, it is I have a condition rely on the column K to decide which row of data i will generate. If col K is **YES** than it will generate that row of data if col K is  **No** then I will not generate that row to the new sheet.

**My problem is how can i generate a new worksheet and fetch those mandatory fields to a new worksheet with yes or no condition in col K**
 Thank you

It is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim selected As Range
Dim newws As Worksheet
Dim yesno As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim justify As Boolean

lastrow = Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row

Set rng = Range("B3:J" & lastrow)
Set yesno = Range("K3:K" & lastrow)

Worksheets("Important").Add after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set wks = ActiveSheet
 For Each selected In rng
If rng.Cells.Value = "Yes" Then
justify = True
Worksheets("Important").Copy
Else
If rng.Cells.Value = "No" Then
justify = False

Set newws = Nothing
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You are cycling through column B and not Column K.  The `For Each` loop should be `For each selected in yesno` not rng.
2. The method by which you are creating the sheet will not work.  I like to break them into two lines. I declares a worksheet variable 'tws'.

   Set tws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
   tws.Name = ("Important")
3. The copy/paste line is incorrect.  The syntax is `range(source).copy range(destination)`

So all together the following will do what is asked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ss As Range, cel As Range
Dim yesno As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim justify As Boolean
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim tlr&, i&

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to the worksheet with the data
With wks
    lastrow = .Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row

    Set yesno = .Range("K3:K" & lastrow)

    Set tws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
    tws.Name = ("Important")
    Set rng = Union(.Range("B3"), .Range("D3"), .Range("E3"), .Range("H3"), .Range("I3"))
    rng.Copy tws.Range("B1")
    For Each ss In yesno
        If LCase(ss.Value) = "yes" Then
            'set rng to the 5 cells desired.
            Set rng = Union(.Range("B" & ss.Row), .Range("D" & ss.Row), .Range("E" & ss.Row), .Range("H" & ss.Row), .Range("I" & ss.Row))
            tlr = tws.Range("B" & tws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 'find next empty row on target sheet
            rng.Copy tws.Cells(tlr, "B") 'Change to starting column desired.
            justify = True 'not sure what this is for.
        ElseIf LCase(ss.Value) = "no" Then
            justify = False 'not sure what this is for.
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

I changed the `selected` to `ss` just to stay away from `selection` and so I did not need to type so much.

I also declared `rng` as the required cells to copy.

Edited to add titles

Comment: Hi scott i have tried the code it can generate a new worksheet but it is empty in the new sheet

Comment: What if i want to copy the title as well?

Comment: Either one of two things are happening.  Either the page with the data is not the active page when the macro is run or the in column K there is no "Yes" spelled exactly like that with the capital Y.  I have changed the code slightly, lets try naming the sheet directly.  there is a place that you will need to provide tha actual sheet name, I have commented where.  Try that.

Comment: I have tried the code and it only generate the last row of data and i spent like an hour and still don't know how to figure it out :(

Comment: @NicholasAggerLui Email me the workbook and I will look at it. scott.craner@gmail.com